# Applymap only to certain rows according to its index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df and a couple of functions. Basically I would like apply these functions using applymap, but only to certain rows according to it's index.

Something like: applymap(function1) if index = X, applymap(function2) if index = Y. And so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might be looking at `apply` instead of `applymap`. Can you give a specific functions?

Comment: They're piecewise functions. For example:
def function(x): if x in range (0,10): y = .5 elif x in range(10,20): y = .4

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `np.select`

```
cond1 = df.index=='X'
cond2 = df.index=='Y'

val1 = df[col].applymap(function1)
val2 = df[col].applymap(function2)

out = np.select([con1, con2], [val1, val2])
```